# write.xlsx is converting NA to blank cells in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I am using the function write.xlsx to convert a data frame to an xlsx file ( In R 3.6.1) . The dataframe I am looking at has NA's in some of the rows, however when I save the dataframe as an xlsx file they appear as blank cells, I have tried using the optional argument showNA but this doesn't work, I have also tried the function write_xlsx but this doesn't have that argument.

Any help appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: Thats worked, thanks a lot! I read online the argument was showNA haha been annoying me for longer then I care to admit. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could specify the `keepNA` argument in `write.xlsx`.  According to the `?write.xlsx`

> keepNA - If TRUE, NA values are converted to #N/A (or na.string, if not NULL) in Excel, else NA cells will be empty

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(df1, 'yourfile.xlsx', keepNA = TRUE)
```